# How to refresh playerprefs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Balloon popping game, and I want to get a prize for some amount of score for example if you made a score of 10 you get a sticker or if you made a score of 20 you get a keyholder, and if you have score 0 you get a try again text so the problem is that when I finish the game it displays the try again text then when you open a different program (like going to a folder or anything outside of unity the text refresh and then I get the right text. I have tried using update, LateUpdate and FixedUpdate but nothing changes.

Here is the script:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour
 {
 //public string levelToLoad;
 public float timer = 60f;
 public Text timerSeconds;
 public GameObject panelWin, score, time, pausa;
 public int _playerScore;
 public Text premio;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
 timerSeconds = GetComponent<Text>();
 time.SetActive(true);
 panelWin.SetActive(false);
 Time.timeScale = 1;
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void LateUpdate ()
 {
 timer -= Time.deltaTime;
 timerSeconds.text = timer.ToString("f0");
 if (timer <=0)
 {
     if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Points"))
     {
         _playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Points");
         if (_playerScore == 0)
         {
             premio.text = "Intenta de nuevo!";
         }
         else
         {
             if (_playerScore >= 1 && _playerScore <= 10)
             {
                 premio.text = "Tu premio es: una calco Bebé a bordo";
             }
             else
             {
                 if (_playerScore >= 11 && _playerScore <= 20)
                 {
                     premio.text = "Tu premio es: un llavero Huggies";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if (_playerScore >= 21 && _playerScore <= 30)
                     {
                         premio.text = "Tu premio es: un pack de toallitas";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if (_playerScore >= 31 && _playerScore <= 40)
                         {
                             premio.text = "Tu premio es: un pack de 
pañales";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if (_playerScore >= 41 && _playerScore >= 50)
                             {
                                 premio.text = "Tu premio es: un bolso 
Huggies";
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }

             }
         }


     }
     panelWin.SetActive(true);
     score.SetActive(false);
     //time.SetActive(false);
     pausa.SetActive(false);
     if (panelWin == true)
     {
         Time.timeScale = 0;
     }

 }
 }
 public void DoARestart()
 {
 SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
 }
 public void Menu()
 {
 SceneManager.LoadScene("TitleScreen");
 }
 }
```

This is  the GameController Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameControllerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform balloonPrefab;
public Text      scoreDisplay;
public Text scoreDisplayWin;

public int             _playerScore        = 0;
//private int             _multiplier         = 1;
private float           _timeSinceLastSpawn = 0.0f;
private float           _timeToSpawn        = 0.0f;
private List<Transform> _balloons;


private const int BALLOON_POOL = 30;

void Start () {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Points", 0);
    _balloons = new List<Transform>();
    for (int i = 0; i < BALLOON_POOL; i++) {
        Transform balloon = Instantiate(balloonPrefab) as Transform;
        balloon.parent = this.transform;
        _balloons.Add(balloon);
    }
    SpawnBalloon();

    GameStart();
}

/*void InitMultiplier() {
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Multiplier")) {
        _multiplier = Mathf.Max (1, PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Multiplier"));
    }
}*/

void InitPoints() {
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Points"))
    {
        _playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Points");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    _timeSinceLastSpawn += Time.deltaTime;

    if (_timeSinceLastSpawn >= _timeToSpawn)
    {
        SpawnBalloon();
    }

}

void SpawnBalloon() {
    _timeSinceLastSpawn = 0.0f;
    _timeToSpawn = Random.Range (0.0f, 2.0f);
    foreach (Transform b in _balloons) {
        BalloonScript bs = b.GetComponent<BalloonScript>();
        if (bs && !bs.isActive) {
            bs.Activate();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void AddPoints(int points=1) {
    _playerScore += points;
    UpdateScoreDisplay();
}

public void GameOver() {
    SavePoints();
    SceneManager.LoadScene("TitleScreen");
}

void UpdateScoreDisplay() {
    scoreDisplay.text = "Puntaje: " + _playerScore.ToString();// + "(x" + 
_multiplier.ToString() + ")";
    scoreDisplayWin.text = "Tu puntaje es: " + _playerScore.ToString();
}

public void GameStart() {
    InitPoints();
    //InitMultiplier();
    UpdateScoreDisplay();
}

void OnApplicationPause() {
    SavePoints();
}

void OnApplicationQuit() {
    SavePoints();
}

void SavePoints() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Points", _playerScore);
}

}
```

I dont have any errors on the console, would be very glad if anyone can help! Thanks!

Comment: @Programmer is not even the same subject, is not about saving or android so how is my question the same?

Comment: *"How to refresh or update playerprefs"* Doesn't that mean saving/overriding existing data?

Comment: no, I mean to refresh as get the last score. but I dont really know if that is the problem, or if im doing something wrong in the if statment, sorry for my english.

Comment: @Programmer can you unmark as duplicate please, so other people can help

Comment: Please change the title. "update playerprefs" means to save or write to old vales. Just reopened it

Comment: Just a note: Playerprefs is strongly ***unrecommended*** for saving stuff like scores. It's real easy to cheat it (it's plain text). It's intended as a built-in way of saving **preferences** (settings, like BGM volume, control-schemes, preferred resolution, VSync flags, and so on...) Consider at least saving in binary format using `BinaryFormatter` instead.

Comment: Thanks @AlmightyR but the game wont be public. but that is not the problem here, so if can help with the real problem would be greate!

Comment: As for the problem, it's probably where you're ***setting*** the `Points`. I strongly suspect a misaligned **execution order**, where the script responsible for updating the `Points` value is run ***after*** `CountDownTimer` is: **1)** This script makes the check for `_playerScore == 0` and results in `true` because `Points` hasn't been updated yet an is still a default `0` (thus printing `"Intenta de nuevo!"`). --- **2)** The script responsible for updating `Points` with the score is run (too late). --- **3)** Next frame, the check is run again (`LateUpdate`): Different `Points` => result.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code where `Points` gets updated/set? So that we can confirm this scenario? --- Also, add `Debug.Log("Points: "+_playerScore);` right after `_playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Points");`... And something like `Debug.Log("Points at set: "+PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Points"));` right after you set `Points`, so we can check and confirm the order in which things are happening. --- If it prints the `"Points at set"` string ***before*** it prints `"Points:"`, then the problem is somewhere else. Otherwise, the problem is bad execution order.

Comment: Thanks @AlmightyR ! I will try that and also edit the question!

Comment: Where is `GameOver()` called?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You're not updating `Points` properly before it's used in CountDownTimer's `LateUpdate()`... Here is how your program flows:

1. In the **GameController** script, you set `Points` to `0` at `Start()`.
2. In the **CountDownTimer** script, on every `LateUpdate()` (every frame), you check if `playerPrefs.HasKey("Points")`, which, from the first frame where `GameController` is enabled (runs `Start()`), which is probably the first game frame overall too, will result in `true`.
3. Right after that, you set `_playerScore` to `Points` (`0`), and selects a value for `premio.text` based on that.
4. Since...

   1. Your `GameController.GameOver()` is probably not called in the first frame of the script/game, in fact, probably not called for several frames.
   2. And since in the `CountDownTimer.LateUpdate()` (called every frame, including the first), from the first frame where `GameControler.enabled == true` (which is probably the first frame overall), `Points` will be there and equal `0`.
5. In `CountDownTimer.LateUpdate()`, you will get `"Intenta de nuevo!"` from the first frame where `GameControler.enabled == true` (which is probably the first frame overall), for several frames, until `GameControler.GameOver()` is called.